# Pattern for accessing data outside of transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have a Spring Boot App with Spring Data JPA with hibernate and MySQL as the data store.

I have 3 layers in my application:

1. API Service
2. Application Service
3. Domain Service ( with Repository)

The role of Application Service is to convert hibernate-backed POJOs to DTOs given some business logic.

**POJO**

SchoolClass.java

```
@Column
Long id;

@Column
String name;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "schoolClass")
List<Book> books;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "schoolClass")
List<Student> students;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "schoolClass")
List<Schedule> schedules;
```

**Domain Service** - My transaction boundary is at the Domain Service layer.

SchoolClassService.java

```
@Autowired
private SchoolClassRepository repository;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public SchoolClass getClassById(Long id) {
  return repository.findById(id);
}
```

**Application Service**

SchoolClassAppService.java

```
@Autowired
private SchoolClassService domainService;

public SchoolClassDto getClassById(Long id) {
  SchoolClass schoolClass = domainService.getClassById(id);
  // convert POJO to DTO;
  return SchoolClassDto;
}
```

My problem is that at times the child entities on SchoolClass are empty when I try to access them in SchoolClassAppService. Not all of them, but out of the three, two would work fine but the third one would be empty. I tried to mark the children lists to be eagerly fetched, but apparently only two collections can be eagerly fetched before Hibernate starts throwing exceptions and it also does not sound like good practice to always load all the objects. I do not get `LazyInitializationException`, just the list is empty.

I have tried to just call the getter on all lists in the domain service method before returning it just to load all data for the POJO but that does not seem like a clean practice.

Are there any patterns available which keep the transaction boundaries as close to the persistence layer as possible while still make it viable to process the data even after the transaction has been closed?

Comment: Did you inspect your `SchoolClass` inside the `SchoolClassRepository` within in the transaction? Are you sure all those children can be pulled correctly?

Comment: If you are not swallowing exceptions this has probably more to do with the saving not happening as intended than with the loading.

Comment: The data was saved correctly. And if I just call the getters for all the child lists while I am inside the transaction, the data is present and its also available once the transaction is closed.

Comment: So far I can clue about is you can't **eager fetch** two collections simultaneously. https://developer.jboss.org/thread/107877

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your collections are sometimes empty, but maybe that just how the data is?

I created [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) for exactly that use case. You essentially define DTOs for JPA entities as interfaces and apply them on a query. It supports mapping nested DTOs, collection etc., essentially everything you'd expect and on top of that, it will improve your query performance as it will generate queries fetching just the data that you actually require for the DTOs.

The entity views for your example could look like this

```
@EntityView(SchoolClass.class)
interface SchoolClassDto {
  String getName();
  List<BookDto> getBooks();
}
@EntityView(Book.class)
interface BookDto {
  // Whatever data you need from Book
}
```

Querying could look like this

```
List<SchoolClassDto> dtos = entityViewManager.applySetting(
  EntityViewSetting.create(SchoolClassDto.class),
  criteriaBuilderFactory.create(em, SchoolClass.class)
).getResultList();
```

Just keep in mind that DTOs shouldn't just be copies your entities but should be designed to fit your specific use case.